# Suppressing matching groups in Python regex

Tags: python, regex

I have the following code to match an escaped string:

```
match_str = r'''(["/']).*?(?<!\\)(\\\\)*\1'''
test_str = r'''"This is an \"escaped\" string" and this isn't.'''

mo = re.match(match_str, test_str)

if mo:
    print mo.group()
```

which works fine.

However, while I understand I need the groups in there to handle the repetition, etc., I'm not interested in using the groups after the match. I know I can just call `mo.group(0)` and get the whole thing, but for what I am doing it would be helpful if it could behave as if no groups were found in this type of case, i.e. that `mo.groups()` would return `(None)`.

Is there any way to do this?

EDIT: If it helps, I'm trying to do something like this:

```
ma = [myclass("regex1nogroups", [func1]),
      myclass("regex2twogroups", [func2, func3]),
      myclass("regex3fourgroups", [func4, func5, func6, func7]),
      myclass("regex4nogroups", [func8])]

for mc in ma:
    mo = re.match(mc.pattern, str_to_match)
    if mo:
        for n in range(len(mc.funclist)):
            result = mo.group(n+1 if mo.groups() else 0)
            mc.funclist[n](result)
```

using the length of the list of functions to determine how many groups the regex should produce. I could add an extra flag member to `myclass` to be true if I want to just assume there are no groups, but it would be nice to avoid this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add in `?:` and you get a non-capturing group:

```
(?:\\\\)
```

Comment: If I add that to the very first group, though, the \1 at the end appears to not work.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths: You can't reference non-capturing groups. Why are capturing groups a problem for you?

Comment: Hence my problem! If I need to use a capturing group to make the match work, I can't use non-capturing groups, so I was asking if there was any way to suppress them.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths: Why do you need to suppress them?

Comment: To put it briefly, I have a class with a pattern as a class attribute, and a list of functions to call for each group when there are multiple groups. In this case, I want the whole pattern to be treated as one group and sent to a single function, so I'd like it to behave as if just one group (or none) was identified. I can write a workaround to cope with it, but it would be nice to have some code that could cope with it without special modifications.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths: You can't really put anything into the regex to do that.

Comment: I looked around and I couldn't find anything either, wasn't sure if there was some smart way to make the re module do something like that, though, if not actually in the regex itself.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up just approaching the problem in a different way, and taking the obvious step of looking at the length of the function list, rather than looking at `re.groups()`:

```
ma = [myclass("regex1nogroups", [func1]),
      myclass("regex2twogroups", [func2, func3]),
      myclass("regex3fourgroups", [func4, func5, func6, func7]),
      myclass("regex4nogroups", [func8])]

for mc in ma:
    mo = re.match(mc.pattern, str_to_match)
    if mo:
        for n,f in enumerate(mc.funclist):
            result = mo.group(n+1 if len(mc.funclist) > 1 else 0)
            f(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to suppress a group in a **list** of str. use '.str' and replace
ie :

```
df.col_str where ".str" able you to apply str methods on the list.
```

output :

```
2             blabla...Length=45
3             bloblo...Length=44
4          VANILLE ...Length=448
5             fooo 1...Length=44
6             Colori...Length=70
```

but you want to remove `...Length=99` with 99 any numerics. (48, xx,...) so you will use `f'?{your_constant_pattern}[0-9]+'` with `[0-9]+` because I want it ends by any number.

Use a replace :

```
df.col_str.str.replace(pat="(?:...Length=[0-9]+)", repl="", regex=True)
```

output :

```
    2             blabla
    3             bloblo
    4            VANILLE
    5             fooo 1
    6             Colori
```

or

```
df.col_str.replace(to_replace="(?:...Length=[0-9]+)", value="", regex=True, inplace=True)
```